# How to get information of the registered routes in Nest js microservices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, microservices, nestjs

I am new here. I am building a open source application based on Nest JS. It contains number of controllers and in each controller I registered many routes using message mapper (because I am using nest microservices with redis for message queue purpose). I want to access registered routes details in the main.ts file. I can access all the registered route links but can't get all the details about each route like route's linked method, methods information etc..,

**The information I need is**
1.Method name which mapped to specific link
2.number of arguments of that method
3.other details about that method

Is there any way to do?